# Bulk renaming photos and adding letters to duplicate file names in Powershell

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a question about a powershell script. I want to rename a bunch of photos within a folder. I have a .csv file of the old names and the new names. This is a section of that file:

```
OldFile NewFile
{5858AA5A-DB1B-475A-808E-0BFF0B885E5B}.jpeg 975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Notes-20200828.jpeg
{FA1E4CEE-0AD8-4B40-A5AD-4BB22C0EE4F0}.jpeg 975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Other-20200828.jpeg
{FD20FA44-B3D2-4A6A-B73D-F3BADC2DDE71}.jpeg 975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Vicinity-20200831.jpeg
{E0DDA4CD-7783-417C-9BE0-705FFA08CD17}.jpeg 975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Vicinity-20200831.jpeg
{76DC6315-942D-444C-BA04-92FC9B9FF1A5}.jpeg 975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Vicinity-20200831.jpeg
{3C853453-0A0D-40B5-B3B7-B0F84F92D512}.jpeg 975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Vicinity-20200831.jpeg
```

Many of the new file names will be duplicates. For those files, I want to add a letter (A,B,C, so on) in the middle of the name at an exact location.

For example, if the file, 975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Vicinity-20200831.jpeg, is a duplicate, I want to add "A" right after "Vicinity", so that the file is called 975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-VicinityA-20200831.jpeg. The letter will always be at that exact same location (right before the third -).

This is the script I have so far. I know it's not right and I haven't been able to even attempt at adding the letter within the script. (I'm a complete Powershell newbie.)

```
$filesToRename = Import-CSV C:\Users\clair\OneDrive\Documents\JOA\batch_photos\Rename_Central_Aguirre.csv   
foreach ($file In $filesToRename) {
    if (Test-Path $file.NewFile) {
        $letter = -begin { $count= 1 } -Process { Rename-Item $file.OldFile
            "file-$([char](96 + $count)).jpeg"; $count++}
    } else {
        Rename-Item $file.OldFile $file.NewFile
    }
}
```

Could I get some guidance on how to achieve this file naming system?

Thanks!!!

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/errors/sample-data. why? lookee ... >>> Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It's a picture of sample data from excel. I'm not sure how to post it without it becoming a picture

Comment: CSV files ARE NOT excel files. [*grin*] they are structured plain text files. ///// if you really have an excel file & want folks to be able to USE it in this Question, then it needs to be text. you can either select it in excel and paste it _as plain text_, OR export it as a CSV file and use notepad to copy the info.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you! I've updated it. (I'm a complete newbie with this stuff)

Comment: neat! now, please wrap the sample in code markers to make it easy for folks to read ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When renaming files using a character from the alphabet will mean you will only have 26 options. If that is enough for you, you can do the following:

```
$alphabet      = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
$folderPath    = 'D:\Test'
$filesToRename = Import-CSV C:\Users\clair\OneDrive\Documents\JOA\batch_photos\Rename_Central_Aguirre.csv

foreach ($file In $filesToRename) {
    $oldFile = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $file.OldFile
    if (Test-Path $oldFile -PathType Leaf) {
        # split the new filename into workable parts
        $newName = $file.NewFile
        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($newName)
        $parts = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($newName) -split '-'
        $suffix = $parts[-1]
        $prefix = $parts[0..($parts.Count -2)] -join '-'
        $charToAppend = 0    # counter to go through the characters in the alphabet. 0..25
        while (Test-Path (Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $newName) -PathType Leaf) {
            if ($charToAppend -gt 25) {
                # bail out if al characters have been used up
                throw "Cannot rename file '$($file.OldFile)', because all characters A-Z are already used"
            }
            $newName = '{0}{1}-{2}{3}' -f $prefix, $alphabet[$charToAppend++], $suffix, $extension
        } 
        Rename-Item -Path $oldFile -NewName $newName
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "File '$($file.OldFile)' not found"
    }
}
```

---

Before:

```
D:\TEST
    {3C853453-0A0D-40B5-B3B7-B0F84F92D512}.jpeg
    {5858AA5A-DB1B-475A-808E-0BFF0B885E5B}.jpeg
    {76DC6315-942D-444C-BA04-92FC9B9FF1A5}.jpeg
    {E0DDA4CD-7783-417C-9BE0-705FFA08CD17}.jpeg
    {FA1E4CEE-0AD8-4B40-A5AD-4BB22C0EE4F0}.jpeg
    {FD20FA44-B3D2-4A6A-B73D-F3BADC2DDE71}.jpeg
```

After:

```
D:\TEST
    975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Notes-20200828.jpeg
    975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Other-20200828.jpeg
    975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-Vicinity-20200831.jpeg
    975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-VicinityA-20200831.jpeg
    975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-VicinityB-20200831.jpeg
    975NNNN-AGUIRRESUGARASSOCSTACK-VicinityC-20200831.jpeg
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but when I ran it (after subbing in my folder path), nothing happened. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: @ClaireSchmidt Ok, I did misspell `$alphabet` in my original answer, but since I did that all through the code, it still runs fine when I test it. I have just tested again and put the results in my answer to show the results. My assumtion here is that your CSV has values separated by commas. Perhaps yours is not and there the values may be separated by another character (the space maybe?). In that case, add `-Delimiter ' '` to the Import-Csv command. Please open it in notepad and check the separator character in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the method.Insert(). This is a small example how it works:

I ve created a txt named 975NNNN-AGUIRRERM1-Vicinity-20200829.txt in C:\Test just for testing purpose, in your example the first code line is to identify the duplicate(s)

```
#Code to identify duplicates (insert your code instead of mine)
$files=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -File  -Name

#The following line indentifies the location of the last "-" (I understand you always have 3 "-" right?)
$DashPos=($files).LastIndexOf("-")

#This inserts on the position $DashPos, the letter "A")
$files.Insert($DashPos,"A")
```